# rails 4 devise confirmation form allows blank emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**Devise Version: 3.4.0**

I have noticed an odd issue with my devise configuration where the Confirmations controller allows blank emails in the create method:

```
  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(resource_params)
    yield resource if block_given?

    if successfully_sent?(resource)

      puts "4 = successfully_sent"
      binding.pry

      respond_with({}, location: :user_verification_sent)

      # respond_with resource, location: :user_verification_sent
    else

      puts "3 = error"
      binding.pry

      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end
```

I should note I am overriding the default setups for devise and this controller is properly linked:

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  before_filter :set_registration_current_step
```

The confirmation form looks like:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { id: "confirm-frm" }) do |f|

  div[class="row"]
    div[class="large-12 columns"]
      = f.email_field(:email, html_options = { class: "large text-field", id: "confirm-email", \
          autocomplete: "off", autocorrect: "off", autocapitalize: "off", spellcheck: "false", \
          maxlength: "100", placeholder: "Email Address", autofocus: true})

  div[class="row"]
    div[class="large-12 large-centered columns"]
      a[href="#" id="confirm-btn" class="button button-flat-grey text-emphasis expand"]
        |Resend Confirmation
        i[class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"]
```

My routes:

```
scope '/account' do
  # confirmation after account is created
  get '/verification', to: 'users/confirmations#verification_sent', as: 'user_verification_sent'
  # verify the user's token that was emailed to them
  get '/confirm', to: 'users/confirmations#show', as: 'user_confirmation'
  get '/confirm/resend', to: 'users/confirmations#new', as: 'new_user_confirmation'
  post '/confirm', to: 'users/confirmations#create'
end
```

And here is the pry snapshot of it showing true:
[image: pry]

Before I manually check the email param, which would fix this, it seems odd that devise allows this to occur.  Am I crazy fellow rubyists?

**UPDATE_1**

I should note, if I dump `resource_class` from `resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(resource_params)` I get:

```
=> #<User id: nil, agreed_to_terms: false, date_of_birth: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, username: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

**This occurs when the user tries to request a confirmation but does not enter an email address.** The db can be empty.

**UPDATE_2**

When I started dissecting the gem, I think I found where this is occurring....

```
    260: def send_confirmation_instructions(attributes={})
    261:
 => 262:   binding.pry
    263:
    264:
    265:
    266:   confirmable = find_by_unconfirmed_email_with_errors(attributes) if reconfirmable
    267:   unless confirmable.try(:persisted?)
    268:     confirmable = find_or_initialize_with_errors(confirmation_keys, attributes, :not_found)
    269:   end
    270:   confirmable.resend_confirmation_instructions if confirmable.persisted?
    271:   confirmable
    272: end

[1] pry(User)> find_by_unconfirmed_email_with_errors(attributes)
=> #<User id: nil, agreed_to_terms: false, date_of_birth: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, username: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[2] pry(User)> if reconfirmable
[2] pry(User)*   puts true
[2] pry(User)* end
true
=> nil
[3] pry(User)> confirmable = find_by_unconfirmed_email_with_errors(attributes) if reconfirmable
=> #<User id: nil, agreed_to_terms: false, date_of_birth: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, username: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[4] pry(User)> confirmable.try(:persisted?)
=> false
[5] pry(User)> unless confirmable.try(:persisted?)
[5] pry(User)*   puts "go
[5] pry(User)* "
[5] pry(User)* end
go
=> nil
[6] pry(User)> find_or_initialize_with_errors(confirmation_keys, attributes, :not_found)
=> #<User id: nil, agreed_to_terms: false, date_of_birth: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, username: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[7] pry(User)> confirmable.persisted?
=> false
[8] pry(User)>
```

**UPDATE_3**

So if I create a user record it looks like:

```
[3] pry(main)> User.all
2014-10-26 15:48:42.161 [DEBUG]::: User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" (pid:4440)
=> [#<User id: 2, agreed_to_terms: true, date_of_birth: "1994-03-02", first_name: "TestFirst", last_name: "TestLast", username: "testuser", email: "test@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$Zu7wI3GC55WC3lnRzATCtetP4rWCpeRNLHwTDc0rGgD...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: "3574edb740c64d826b6da4a8f1365a1b753f6b483e10817282...", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2014-10-26 22:48:34", unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: "2014-10-26 22:48:34", updated_at: "2014-10-26 22:48:34">]
```

And from my digging into the gem, this has something to do with required attributes and the **find_or_initialize_with_errors** method.  Still tracking.... Not sure here..

**UPDATE_4**

Here is my current `User` model code and I am using the gem '[validates_email_format_of](https://github.com/validates-email-format-of/validates_email_format_of)':

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :email_confirmation, :password_confirmation

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable
         #:timeoutable :=> Should not use rememberable and timeoutable together

  validates :username, :date_of_birth, :first_name, :last_name,
    :agreed_to_terms, :email_confirmation, :password_confirmation, presence: true

  validates :email,
    allow_nil: false,
    allow_blank: false,
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
    email_format: { check_mx: true }

  validates :username, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { minimum: 5 }

  validates_confirmation_of :email

  validates_date :date_of_birth, before: lambda { 18.years.ago }
end
```

**UPDATE_5**

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # The secret key used by Devise. Devise uses this key to generate
  # random tokens. Changing this key will render invalid all existing
  # confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens in the database.
  config.secret_key = Rails.application.secrets.my_devise_secret_key

  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class
  # with default 'from' parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = Rails.application.secrets.my_devise_from_email

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication. Each entry
  # given should be a request method and it will automatically be passed to the
  # find_for_authentication method and considered in your model lookup. For instance,
  # if you set :request_keys to [:subdomain], :subdomain will be used on authentication.
  # The same considerations mentioned for authentication_keys also apply to request_keys.
  # config.request_keys = []

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable params authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.params_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database (email + password) authentication.
  # config.params_authenticatable = true

  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Auth is enabled. False by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable http authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.http_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database authentication. The supported strategies are:
  # :database      = Support basic authentication with authentication key + password
  # config.http_authenticatable = false

  # If http headers should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # The realm used in Http Basic Authentication. 'Application' by default.
  # config.http_authentication_realm = 'Application'

  # It will change confirmation, password recovery and other workflows
  # to behave the same regardless if the e-mail provided was right or wrong.
  # Does not affect registerable.
  config.paranoid = true

  # By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for
  # particular strategies by setting this option.
  # Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
  # may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
  # passing skip: :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # By default, Devise cleans up the CSRF token on authentication to
  # avoid CSRF token fixation attacks. This means that, when using AJAX
  # requests for sign in and sign up, you need to get a new CSRF token
  # from the server. You can disable this option at your own risk.
  # config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = true

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 10. If
  # using other encryptors, it sets how many times you want the password re-encrypted.
  #
  # Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
  # your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
  # a value less than 10 in other environments. Note that, for bcrypt (the default
  # encryptor), the cost increases exponentially with the number of stretches (e.g.
  # a value of 20 is already extremely slow: approx. 60 seconds for 1 calculation).
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  # Setup a pepper to generate the encrypted password.
  config.pepper = Rails.application.secrets.my_devise_pepper

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming their account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming their account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
  # the user cannot access the website without confirming their account.
  config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 0.days

  # A period that the user is allowed to confirm their account before their
  # token becomes invalid. For example, if set to 3.days, the user can confirm
  # their account within 3 days after the mail was sent, but on the fourth day
  # their account can't be confirmed with the token any more.
  # Default is nil, meaning there is no restriction on how long a user can take
  # before confirming their account.
  config.confirm_within = 7.days

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
  # db field (see migrations). Until confirmed, new email is stored in
  # unconfirmed_email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
  config.reconfirmable = true

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  config.confirmation_keys = [ :email ]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  # config.remember_for = 5.days
  config.remember_for = 4.weeks

  # Invalidates all the remember me tokens when the user signs out.
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  # config.extend_remember_period = false

  # Options to be passed to the created cookie. For instance, you can set
  # secure: true in order to force SSL only cookies.
  # This has been set to secure in the Rails 4 initializer
  # config.rememberable_options = { secure: Rails.env == 'production'}

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length.
  config.password_length = 8..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  config.timeout_in = 5.hours

  # If true, expires auth token on session timeout.
  config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = true

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  config.unlock_strategy = :both

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  config.maximum_attempts = 5

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # Warn on the last attempt before the account is locked.
  config.last_attempt_warning = true

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 12.hours

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # Allow you to use another encryption algorithm besides bcrypt (default). You can use
  # :sha1, :sha512 or encryptors from others authentication tools as :clearance_sha1,
  # :authlogic_sha512 (then you should set stretches above to 20 for default behavior)
  # and :restful_authentication_sha1 (then you should set stretches to 10, and copy
  # REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper).
  #
  # Require the `devise-encryptable` gem when using anything other than bcrypt
  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering 'sessions/new', it will first check for
  # 'users/sessions/new'. It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  config.scoped_views = true

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  config.default_scope = :user

  # Set this configuration to false if you want /users/sign_out to sign out
  # only the current scope. By default, Devise signs out all scopes.
  config.sign_out_all_scopes = true

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
  # :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
  # access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
  #
  # If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
  # should add them to the navigational formats lists.
  #
  # The "*/*" below is required to match Internet Explorer requests.
  # config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html]

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete

  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', scope: 'user,public_repo'

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not supported by Devise, or
  # change the failure app, you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
  #
  # config.warden do |manager|
  #   manager.intercept_401 = false
  #   manager.default_strategies(scope: :user).unshift :some_external_strategy
  # end

  # ==> Mountable engine configurations
  # When using Devise inside an engine, let's call it `MyEngine`, and this engine
  # is mountable, there are some extra configurations to be taken into account.
  # The following options are available, assuming the engine is mounted as:
  #
  #     mount MyEngine, at: '/my_engine'
  #
  # The router that invoked `devise_for`, in the example above, would be:
  # config.router_name = :my_engine
  #
  # When using omniauth, Devise cannot automatically set Omniauth path,
  # so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:
  # config.omniauth_path_prefix = '/my_engine/users/auth'
end

Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout 'nested/login'
  Devise::PasswordsController.layout 'nested/passwords'
  Devise::RegistrationsController.layout proc{ |controller| user_signed_in? ? 'application' :  'nested/create' }
  Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout 'nested/create'
  # Devise::UnlocksController.layout 'devise'
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure how devise handles this but because the normal way to send the confirmation is after account creation, or update the validations on your model should handle these cases. That might be the reason why devise does not check if the emails is blank or not at this stage. But this are just thoughts...

Comment: Interesting, that is good point.  Thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: Since I am overriding the default setup, do I have to require it? Like I did the registrations controller?   def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(
      :username, :first_name, :last_name, :agreed_to_terms,
      :date_of_birth, :email, :password, :email_confirmation,
      :password_confirmation
    )}
  end

Comment: I think @IsmaelAbreu is right. The confirmation email is normally sent on create, but you're calling this on the class. Do you already have a User instance? Can you swap that to be `resource. send_confirmation_instructions` instead assuming that `resource` is the User instance?

Comment: @excid3 the create is working correctly, this has to do with the confirmation.  Let's say a user creates and account but loses the email for confirmation.  When they come to the site to resend the confirmation, the form allows a blank email, instead of forcing the email on the form.

Comment: @excid3 I just made a few updates... thoughts on where this is busting? I wonder if I am missing a config...

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu I just made a few updates... thoughts on where this is busting? I wonder if I am missing a config...

Comment: Definitely failing on `find_by_unconfirmed_email_with_errors` it seems. Is the email you submit in the form actually in the DB?

Comment: @excid3 I can submit the form with a blank "" email, and it does not return an error.  That is the odd part, it should come back saying email required right?

Comment: @chrishough Could you paste in your devise initializer contents? I remember there are settings related to required fields in there.

Comment: @wldcordeiro I found it, OMFG, check out this cause in case you see it on our end

Comment: @excid3 I found it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here goes!  If you are googling for this issue, please be warned here is the cause from the devise init:

```
# It will change confirmation, password recovery and other workflows
  # to behave the same regardless if the e-mail provided was right or wrong.
  # Does not affect registerable.
  config.paranoid = false
```

It was finally located in dissecting this method in `authenticatable.rb`:

```
  # Helper for use after calling send_*_instructions methods on a resource.
  # If we are in paranoid mode, we always act as if the resource was valid
  # and instructions were sent.
  def successfully_sent?(resource)
    notice = if Devise.paranoid
      resource.errors.clear
      :send_paranoid_instructions
    elsif resource.errors.empty?
      :send_instructions
    end

    if notice
      set_flash_message :notice, notice if is_flashing_format?
      true
    end
  end
```

Comment: Oh! So in paranoid mode it never shows any errors? Kinda weird.

Comment: The reason it never shows errors in paranoid mode is to prevent an attacker from using error messages to determine if, e.g., an account with a given email exists in the database.